# Need help in using LISTAGG function with DISTINCT

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
Select ID, 
 LISTAGG(DISTINCT VIEW_NM, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY CAST(VISIT_PAGE_NBR as INT)) 
 AS No_Of_Views
FROM db_name.schema_name.tbl_name 
WHERE FLG_COLUMN = '0'
AND SOURCE_CD NOT IN ('1','2','3','4')
AND DATE_CR = '2022-01-01'
GROUP BY ID;
```

I want the VIEW_NM column values to be displayed either in ASC or DESC order. But when I do a DISTINCT VIEW_NM, I'm getting - It is not a valid ORDER BY expression. Need help in fixing this.

Also, I don't want the values of VIEW_NM column to be duplicated. Pls suggest how this can be done..

Comment: Can I use REGEX_REPLACE instead? Kindly guide.

Comment: I tried the below logic using REGEXP_REPLACE with LISTAGG, but the result is not coming in right order..

Comment: SELECT 
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
        LISTAGG (VIEW_NM, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CAST(VISIT_PAGE_NBR as INT)),
        '([^,]+)(,\1)+',
        '\1' 
    ) as NO_OF_VIEWS
  FROM db_name.schema_name.tbl_name 
WHERE FLG_COLUMN = '0'
AND SOURCE_CD NOT IN ('5','7','8','9')
AND DATE_CR = '2022-01-01'
group by visit_id;

Comment: Hi @jenifer - I answered a question that you posted about 2 hours ago, but now you deleted it. Why? Feels a little rude https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70936034/need-help-in-forming-a-sql-query.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and it helped me a lot. I have added the question again.

Comment: I didn't thanked you first for guiding me. I'm so sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Using cte to filter out multiple VIEW_NM per ID(choosing the one with lowest VIST_PAGE_NBR):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ID, VIEW_NM, VISIT_PAGE_NBR::INT AS VISIT_PAGE_NBR
  FROM db_name.schema_name.tbl_name 
  WHERE FLG_COLUMN = '0'
    AND SOURCE_CD NOT IN ('1','2','3','4')
    AND DATE_CR = '2022-01-01'
  QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID,VIEW_NM ORDER BY VISIT_PAGE_NBR) = 1
)
SELECT ID,
    LISTAGG(VIEW_VM, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY VISIT_PAGE_NBR) AS No_Of_Views
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: When I try the above query, I am not getting the result VIEW_VM either in ASC or DESC order. What can be done to display the result of VIEW_VM column in ASC or DESC order? Can anyone suggest please?

Comment: @Jenifer Maybe VISIT_PAGE_NBR is a text, then: `LISTAGG(VIEW_VM, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY VISIT_PAGE_NBR::INT) AS No_Of_Views`

Comment: I will check that. Thank you so much :)