# Need help in forming a SQL query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

We have 2 tables called tbl1 and tbl2. It contains columns such as Visit_ID, Customer ID, and so on. There are instances where a Visit_ID will be associated with multiple Customer IDs.

For example, if customer logs into a website, a unique Visit_ID will be generated for each time he visits the website.

In one visit, multiple customers can login to their accounts and make individual purchases.

There are instances where a visit will be associated to multiple customer IDs. If there are more than 2 instances, append any other retail customer ID instances in this column.

For instances there are visit, which had 200 Customer IDs attached to that visit.

For example, if there are 7 Customer IDs in 1 visit, for  Customer 1,
it should have the first customer 1. For  Customer 2, we will need to display the 2nd customer ID.

For 3rd to 7, all those 5 will be comma separated.

Can someone help how to frame a SQL query using this logic?

```
   with CTE as (
    SELECT
    visit_id,
    B.visitpg_nbr::INT AS visitpg_nbr,
     CUSTOMER_ID,
  dense_rank()over( PARTITION BY VISIT_ID order by CUSTOMER_ID) as rank
from
    db_name.schema_name.tbl_1 A
    JOIN db_name.schema_name.tbl_2 B
    ON B.id_column  = A.id_column 
    JOIN db_name.schema_name.tbl_3 C
    ON CAST(C.xid as VARCHAR)= A.CUSTOMER_ID
    WHERE flg_col = '0'
    AND so_cd NOT IN ('0','1','2','3')
    AND DATE_COL = '2022-01-17'
    and visit_id='12345'
      ORDER BY visitpg_nbr
    )
    
    select  VISIT_ID, arr[0], arr[1], array_to_string( array_slice(arr, 2, 99999), ', ')
    from (
    select VISIT_ID, array_agg(distinct CUSTOMER_ID) within group(order by CUSTOMER_ID) arr
    from CTE
    group by 1
    );
```

Thanks for those who have responded. I really appreciate their guidance. The logic worked fine. When I'm joining 3 tables inside CTE, I'm getting lot of duplicates. I want to eliminate the duplicate values.

When I run the below query that I have included inside CTE, I'm getting records which are duplicates.

```
SELECT
        visit_id,
        B.visitpg_nbr::INT AS visitpg_nbr,
         CUSTOMER_ID,
      dense_rank()over( PARTITION BY VISIT_ID order by CUSTOMER_ID) as rank
    from
        db_name.schema_name.tbl_1 A
        JOIN db_name.schema_name.tbl_2 B
        ON B.id_column  = A.id_column 
        JOIN db_name.schema_name.tbl_3 C
        ON CAST(C.xid as VARCHAR)= A.CUSTOMER_ID
        WHERE flg_col = '0'
        AND so_cd NOT IN ('0','1','2','3')
        AND DATE_COL = '2022-01-17'
        and visit_id='12345'
          ORDER BY visitpg_nbr

Row      VISIT_ID    CUSTOMER_ID          VISITPG_NBR     RANK 
**1         12345      100                      1                1**
2         12345      100                      2                1
3         12345      100                      3                1
4         12345      100                      4                1
5         12345      100                      5                1

**6         67891      101                      6                2**
7         67891      101                      7                2
8         67891      101                      8                2
9         67891      101                      9                2
10        67891      101                      10               2

**11        78910      102                      11               3**
12        78910      102                      12               3
13        78910      102                      13               3
14        78910      102                      14               3
```

Is there any logic to display the distinct results in the CTE temp table?

The final result should be populated as below.

```
VISIT_ID    First_Customer Second_Customer  Other_Customers

1            100            101             102,103,104,105,106
2            200            201             202,203,204,205
```

First Customer_ID should get displayed in the First_Customer column, Second_Customer_Id should get displayed in Second_Customer column.. All the other customer_ids should be displayed in the final column and it should be comma separated.

Also, I wanted the results to be ordered by **visitpg_nbr**

Comment: Can you add some sample data and how the correct result would look?

Comment: Could you please check now?

Comment: I still cannot find sample data.

Comment: VISIT_ID    First_Customer Second_Customer  Other_Customers

1            100            101             102,103,104,105,106
2            200            201             202,203,204,205                                                               The results should be like this

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get this with `array_agg()`, and then choosing the first, second, and subsequent (`array_slice()`) elements:

```sql
with data as (
    select *
    from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf100.orders
    where o_custkey between 5411266 and 5411290
)

select o_custkey, arr[0], arr[1], array_to_string(array_slice(arr, 2, 99999), ', ')
from (
    select o_custkey, array_agg(o_orderkey) within group(order by o_orderdate) arr
    from data
    group by 1 
);
```

You might need to get unique ids in case there are many, you can solve that with a subquery before `array_agg()`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jenifer, hope you are having a good Stack Overflow experience. Please remember to upvote and accept the answers that have helped you (every question you've asked so far would love to get an accepted answer if they worked for you)

Comment: Thanks Felipe. I'm really having a great experience with stack overflow. Every answers helped me a lot and you guys made my work easier. I really appreciate your support. Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to hear this! Now please accept the answers people have given you throughout https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

slightly different to Felipe's answer, not sure which would be more performant. I suspect his, but anyways here is another way to try it.

```
SELECT visit_id, first_customer, second_customer 
    ,array_agg(other_ids) within group (order by order_id) as other_customer
FROM(
    SELECT visit_id,
        order_id,
        first_value(customer_id) over (partition by visit_id order by order_id) as first_customer,
        first_value(customer_id) over (partition by visit_id order by order_id) as second_customer,
        IFF(row_number() over (partition by visit_id order by order_id) > 2, customer_id, null) as other_ids
    FROM VALUES
        (1,100, 1),
        (1,101, 2),
        (1,102, 3),
        (1,103, 5),
        (1,104, 6),
        (1,105, 6),
        (1,106, 7),
        (2,200, 1),
        (2,201, 2),
        (2,202, 3),
        (2,203, 4)
        v(visit_id, customer_id, order_id)
    )
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

| VISIT_ID | FIRST_CUSTOMER | SECOND_CUSTOMER | OTHER_CUSTOMER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 100 | [ 102, 103, 104, 105, 106 ] |
| 2 | 200 | 200 | [ 202, 203 ] |

Comment: Thank you so much Simeon. I will try this as well.